# How do I force an android app to use secure SSL/TLS connection instead of http without changing code?

Tags: android, ssl, https

The challenge I have is to convert an android app that uses HTTP connection to HTTPS connection without rewriting the code?

What are the options available to achieve the above challenge on a device without a root access?

Answer (score 2):

Any solution that relies on server-side redirections (from HTTP to HTTPS) will be vulnerable to MITM attacks (see [this answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/28443/11628)).

If the addresses in this app are configurable, just change them to use your HTTPS URLs.

Otherwise, you can of course use a server-side redirection to mitigate the risk slightly, but that won't prevent downgrade MITM attacks (which can happen, perhaps more so when using a mobile device).

Comment: Useful link to the security issue, but as OP states, he can't change the client app

Comment: @RobCowell, I wasn't sure if the `http://` URL were hard-coded within the app, or if it might be configurable. If it's hard-coded there's aren't many options that are MITM-proof. A possible way would be to implement a transparent proxy that would change the URL on the device itself, but I doubt that's possible without rooting the device.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.Unfortunately, url is hardcoded in the app and in some cases I wont have the code for the app.

Comment: Bad luck. You might be able to secure the connection with a VPN perhaps, but the user would have to be running it whenever the app is running. You'd also need to make sure the connection between the VPN end-point and your HTTPS is secure.

Comment: There is no VPN in our case but just a android/iphone device and a webserver which supports https.

Answer (score 0):

If it's always connecting to a known endpoint that's under your control, you could implement something at the target server end of things to redirect, perhaps something like mod_rewrite if it's an Apache server.

Comment: Yes, it is always connecting to a known endpoint, under my control using Apache server...can you be more specific what/how to change on the server side ?

Comment: Plenty of material around - try this one for example http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-apache-force-https-secure-connections.html

Answer (score 0):

There's no much to be rewritten. You basically change your `http://` links to `https://` and that's shall be it. Some problems may appear when endpoint's certificate is self signed or signed by some less popular CA, but you can easily replace your HttpClient with [this one](http://code.google.com/p/httpclientandroidlib/), add issuer's CA to your app and be done with one screen of code basically.

If app is not yours and you got no code, then you could try to tunnel it, by making it accessing the net via your access point which would transparently re-route the packets via ssh tunnel or VPN or whatever else.

If app is not yours but you can have code - that's IMHO best way to go.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. You are correct that app is not mine and have no code in this case and no VPN as well. Given that situation how can I tunnel/re-route it on a device without root access ?

Comment: you cannot on the device directly. You'd need to set up tunneling on your router/access point - android would not know it is tunneled

Comment: OK. So in this case how does android app know it has to authenticate with the server and encrypt the data using private/public key pair stored in the cert ?

Comment: It will not. Do do that app have to support secure connection by itself or you could be able to tell it to use VPN connection handled by Android (so OS will authenticate).